# XPath assertion without namespace

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

How do I make XPath assertion to my XML response if there is no URL in it to declare namespace, the same would go to Script assertion

```
<data contentType="image/png" contentLength="1143">iVBORw0KGgAEAAA0vr3J9P0uQmCC</data>
```

This is all I get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SOAPUI you can use `XPath` even there is no namespace definition on that node (your namespace is probably defined in a parent node of your `<data>` element). In your question it's not clear what you want to do, so for example if you want to check the value of `contentLenght` attribute for your `<data>` element you can use the follow `XPath` to get the value:

`//data/@contentLength`

If you have a Test step request with `<data>` in the response and as you ask you want to make and assert in groovy test step you can do it with the follow code:

```
def content = context.expand('${YourTestRequestName#response#//data/@contentLength}')
log.info content
assert content.equals("1143"), "ASSERT FAIL"
```

If instead you have a string with XML content you can do:

```
def data = '<data contentType="image/png" contentLength="1143">iVBORw0KGgAEAAA0vr3J9P0uQmCC</data>'
def xmlHolder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(data)
def contentLength = xmlHolder.getNodeValue("//data/@contentLength")
log.info contentLength
assert content.equals("1143"), "ASSERT FAIL"
```

At last if you have a test step request it's also possible to make this adding an `XPath Match` assert in your test step request as you can see in the follow image:

[image]

Hope this helps,

Comment: @albcliff when we extract nodes like ${Step#Response#//*[local-name()="heme"]//} it extracts namespace as well example <mr:Entry xmlns:mr="http://www.example.com">
                              <mr:Key>Name</mr:Key>
                              <mr:Value>www.udzial.com </mr:Value> when the original value does not has this mr in the response

Answer (score 2):

One of the parent elements probably has a namespace declared, and that flows down to the children.

In a simple XPath assertion, you can use the "any" namespace: `//*:data`, which does not have to be declared.